# Can't start screen on a remote server by ssh

Tags: linux, meteor, ssh

I'm trying to start a screen on my remote server using simple-ssh package in my meteor project.

My code:

```
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');

var ssh = new SSH({
host: 'somehost',
user: 'username',
pass: 'password'
});

ssh.exec('screen rtsp2feed 3 3 rtsp://server:port > log.txt', {
out: function(stdout) {
    console.log(stdout);
}
}).start();
```

But screen didn't start. Log file says "Must be connected to a terminal".

How can I fix this?

Comment: **Must be connected to a terminal** say all you need to know. If you want screen, you need to connect it to a terminal.

Comment: @Jakuje so you are saying I can't start screen remotely?

Comment: You can, but you need to connect TTY (terminal or terminal emulator). For that you need *interactive* session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed that simple-ssh had "pty" option, which creates pseudo-terminal